# How to use PageSpeed in a test environment? (password protected)

Tags: testing, pagespeed, test-environments

Google's PageSpeed do not run in a test environment of a website (ProdPreview). 
I guess it's due to the password protection in it.
Is it possible to make PageSpeed run in this environment?
If yes, how to?

PageSpeed give me back the message below, when I try to run it in the ProdPreview environment:

"Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse did not reliably load the requested page. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is responding appropriately to all requests. (Status Code: 401) Dispensing"

No code at all.
It's just a public tool being used in a private environment.

Expected result:  Get the PageSpeed analysis result.
Actual result: As described in "#2 = Provide background including what you've already tried"

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can pass the password-protected website by embedding username and password into the url.

http://username:password@example.com

This url works on any browser but I think it does not work on google pagespeed.

Comment: OK.
Sorry for the late response.
I was moved to a new project.
I will share this tip with the DEV/QA Teams.

Thank you!!!